# How to add screen touch coordinates to real world in Scenform (AR CORE)?

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I want to add an image to an AR view.  I am able to add an image when the plane is rendered. But I want to add even if there is no plane that is rendered. I want to add it to the real-world position of the AR view — I actually want to convert that touched point to World position of AR View.

```
   List<HitResult> hitResult = frame.hitTest(motionEvent);

                if (hitResult.size() != 0) {

//This code works fine
                    HitResult hit = hitResult.get(0);
                    Anchor anchor = hit.createAnchor();
                    AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
                    anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
                    anchors.add(anchor);


                } else {


//This is not Working

                    if (arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession() != null) {

                        Anchor anchor = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession().createAnchor(frame.getCamera().getPose().compose(Pose.makeTranslation(0, 0, -1f)).extractTranslation());
                        AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
                        anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
                        anchors.add(anchor);

                        if (drawingText.equalsIgnoreCase("imagearrow")) {
                            addArrow(anchorNode, arrowType, arrowColor);
                        } 
                    }
                }
```

I am not getting the exact position of the touched point in AR View.

Answer (score -1):

After Lots of Work I am able to find the answer.
You have to create pose according to ray position of your camera and have to calculate position and rotation according to your camera position and Ray point of Camera.

```
Camera camera = arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().getCamera();

Ray ray = camera.screenPointToRay(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
Vector3 drawPoint = ray.getPoint(1f);


Log.d("HELLODRWAPOINT", String.valueOf(drawPoint.x));
                        
ArSceneView arSceneView = arFragment.getArSceneView();
com.google.ar.core.Camera coreCamera = arSceneView.getArFrame().getCamera();
if (coreCamera.getTrackingState() != TrackingState.TRACKING) {
    return;
}

float[] position = { drawPoint.x, drawPoint.y, drawPoint.z};
float[] rotation = { camera.getWorldRotation().x,camera.getWorldRotation().y,camera.getWorldRotation().z, camera.getWorldRotation().w };

Session session = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession();
Anchor anchor = session.createAnchor(new Pose(position, rotation));
AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
                        
anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
anchors.add(anchor);
```

Comment: Doesnt work, the Renderable is away from the given coordinate. Suppose I want to enter something at screen's width/2 and height/2 (Centre of screen), its displaying on the bottom right part.